# SpecFlow/Gherkin highlighting in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, specflow, gherkin

Does anyone know if there are any Sublime Text 2 packages available to enable syntax highlighting for SpecFlow / Gherkin specification files?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/864839

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few solutions to integrate Sublime Text with Gherkin, (in this case with Cucumber not SpecFlow): https://makandracards.com/ninjaconcept/9233-how-to-use-cucumber-together-with-sublime-text-2-editor

Or as a Sublime bundle: https://github.com/npverni/cucumber-sublime2-bundle

And specifically related to your question then this gist (mentioned by Blender above) will add gherkin syntax to Sublime Text 2: https://gist.github.com/864839

Note, there seems to be slight issues with this gist, which is fixed by the comments in this: http://expertbeginner.com/2011/04/18/sublime-cucumbe/ (Edit: Gone, [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130905054204/http://expertbeginner.com/2011/04/18/sublime-cucumbe/) copy)

Answer (score 3):

**Here is the Sublime Text Packages**

All-in-one Package for Cucumber: https://github.com/drewda/cucumber-sublime-bundle

For Feature file autocompletes: https://github.com/AndyHitchman/sublime-gherkin-auto-complete

For building cucumber from sublimetext (ctrl+B): https://github.com/Aravin/Cucumber-Build-SublimeText